# block in the class declaration in java

Tags: java

**My Code:**

```
   class Y
   {
        {
            System.out.println("pranav");
            Y a = new Y();
        }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Y b = new Y();
        }
    }
```

**output:**

> infinite loop

My question is flow of control(execution of program) start from where and how it is work can anyone explain please???

Answer (score 2):

This anonymous initializer block is causing your infinite recursion;

```
{
  System.out.println("pranav"); 
  /*Y a=new Y();*/
}
```

Do not instantiate a new `Y` there, that's recursive.

Because that block is copied into the *default* empty constructor;

```
public Y() {
  super();
  System.out.println("pranav"); 
  /*Y a=new Y();*/ // <-- like so.
}
```

Comment: I already did. The initializer block is copied into the (default) constructor.